# Bash Command not found after xxd

Tags: bash, xxd

I'm attempting to get a whitespace-trimmed plain hex dump of a binary file

Command:

```
aes.key.hex=$(xxd -p /tmp/aes.key | tr -d '[:space:]')
```

Failure:

```
bash: aes.key.hex=097b7be16b52de77437882889fc96a27132217867970b014016f5de3e6864b37: command not found
```

What is happening here? I'm able to execute 
`xxd -p /tmp/aes.key` successfully, so the culprit seems like the bash command to trim all whitespaces `tr -d '[:space:]'`

Comment: `.` isn't valid in a variable name, `_` would be the usual equivalent

Answer (score 1):

The periods are the problem. Use underscores instead. Variable names must be of the form `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` (regex).